# Performance: List.Count vs checking a stored variable

Tags: c#, performance, loops, count

I wonder if this makes any difference:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
        {
            //
        }
```

vs

```
int num = values.Count;

for(int=0; i<num; i++)
{

}
```

I think the second approach is better because you don't need to count all the items in each iteration. But I may be wrong. Could someone illuminate me?

Comment: As a general rule, if you're wondering about performance, you should be profiling your app to find where the bottlenecks are.  Modern compilers do a very good job at optimization and the bottlenecks are usually not where one thinks they are.  In _The Practice of Programming_, Brian Kernighan describes how even the very smart people at Bell Labs ended up optimizing the wrong thing.

Comment: You've written the code both ways. **Run it both ways and then you'll know which one is faster**. Use *science* to solve this problem, not *divination*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The list already stores its `Count` internally. The comparison you are doing is related to code style, not performance. Since the compiler will optimize the retrieval of 'Count'

Comment: It isn't possible for the compiler to optimize the retrieval of `Count`, a mutable property on another object. My experiments with optimized IL indicate that `Count` is re-read on every iteration.

Comment: @spender the IL can be transformed by the JIT, try to read the optimized assembly generated by JIT, here are instructions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2006/02/20/535807.aspx

Comment: I don't believe that the JIT is clever enough to make an optimisation that requires it to know if the list is being manipulated from another thread. That sounds somewhat costly to me. I'll take a look at the optimised JIT assembly, but I'm struggling to see how this might be optimised.

Comment: @spender It seems to be just a direct memory read regardless (I.E. the getter body was inlined), I added `values.Add(i)` to the loop body and the generated code didn't change in this regard.

Comment: Ok. There's an inlining optimisation that is made but the value at the location of `Count` is re-read every loop and subject to change.

Comment: @spender Yeah but the `num` variable is read from fixed memory offset every time as well. So they should be equal speed?

Answer (score 18):

Well you can look at the .NET Source code here
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#aa7e01fcb80a917e

```
  public int Count {
        get {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= 0);
            return _size; 
        }
    }
```

It would appear that .Count property on list does a quick internal check and then returns _size.  So it should be pretty close to the performance of you storing the value yourself.

Answer (score 3):

This entirely depends on what `values` is. `Count` could be implemented completely differently, depending on what the type of this object is.

If you are talking about a generic `List<T>` - then Count is implemented as an internal property that isn't re-evaluated - and therefore is the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it both ways, and using "int num=values.Count;" won by a large margin.
My test used Performance Analyzer and ran the approaches back to back.
Then I switched which one runs first, and again storing it to an integer won.  I guess accessing List.Count is slower and the compiler doesn't optimize it to only run once.

Comment: Could you please share the benchmark?